# MassTransit Multiple Consumers

Tags: masstransit

I have an environment where I have only one app server.  I have some messages that take awhile to service (like 10 seconds or so) and I'd like to increase throughput by configuring multiple instances of my consumer application running code to process these messages.  I've read about the "competing consumer" pattern and gather that this should be avoided when using MassTransit.  According to the MassTransit docs [here](http://masstransit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/gotchas.html), each receive endpoint should have a unique queue name.  I'm struggling to understand how to map this recommendation to my environment.  **Is it possible to have N instances of consumers running that each receive the same message, but only one of the instances will actually act on it?**  In other words, can we implement the "competing consumer" pattern but across multiple queues instead of one?

Or am I looking at this wrong?  Do I really need to look into the "Send" method as opposed to "Publish"?  The downside with "Send" is that it requires the sender to have direct knowledge of the existence of an endpoint, and I want to be dynamic with the number of consumers/endpoints I have.  Is there anything built in to MassTransit that could help with the keeping track of how many consumer instances/queues/endpoints there are that can service a particular message type?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so the "avoid competing consumers" guidance was from when MSMQ was the primary transport. MSMQ would fall over if multiple threads where reading from the queue.

If you are using RabbitMQ, then competing consumers work brilliantly. Competing consumers is the right answer. Each competing consume will use the same receive from endpoint.